# Need select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Consider the following table structure with data -

```
AdjusterID  |  CompanyID  |  FirstName  | LastName | EmailID
============================================================
1001        | Sterling    | Jane        | Stewart  | janexxx@sterlin.com
1002        | Sterling    | David       | Boon     | dav@sterlin.com
1003        | PHH         | Irfan       | Ahmed    | irfan@phh.com
1004        | PHH         | Rahul       | Khanna   | rahul@phh.com
============================================================
```

Where AdjusterID is the primary key. There are no. of adjusters for a company.

I need to have a query that will list single adjuster per company. i.e. I need to get the result as -

```
========================================================
1001 | Sterling  | Jane  | Stewart | janexxx@sterlin.com
1003 | PHH       | Irfan | Ahmed   | irfan@phh.com
========================================================
```

If any one could help me that will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT * FROM Adjusters 
WHERE AdjusterID IN(SELECT min(AdjusterID) 
                    FROM Adjusters GROUP BY CompanyID)
```

There are a handful of other ways involving unions and iteration, but this one is simple enough to get you started.

Edit: this assumes you want the adjuster with the lowest ID, as per your example

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer from Jeremy is a valid one, so I will not repeat it. But you may try another one using a so called tie-breaker:

```
--//using a tie-breaker. Should be very fast on the PK field
--// but it would be good to have an index on CompanyID
SELECT  t.* 
FROM    MyTable t
WHERE   t.AdjusterID = (SELECT TOP 1 x.AdjusterID FROM MyTable x WHERE x.CompanyID = t.CompanyID ORDER BY AdjusterID)
```

It could be better performance-wise. But even more useful it is if you had another column in the table and you wanted to select not just one for each company but the *best* for each company using some other column ranking as a criteria. So instead of `ORDER BY AdjusterID`, you would order by that other column(s).

Comment: Is this really faster? I don't have an execution plan viewer to hand, but I'd have thought a correlated subquery would be slower, for large datasets?

Comment: @Jeremy. If the performance is not your issue, do not bother optimizing. But given proper indices, the tie-breaker should be faster. And it definitely should be in your case as it is on the PK (which I guess is clustered). You should have an index on CompanyID though for both implementation. --- I do not have numbers, but some time ago the tie-breaker worked for me when the sub-query just hang.